# Button doesn't work in custom chrome extension

Tags: javascript, imgur

I tried to make a chrome extension that shows the date, and everything went well, except when I tried to run it. I clicked the button that I coded in, and it wouldn't display what I wanted it to.

Code:

**JS**

```js
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
    document.getElementById("checkday").innerHTML = n;
```

**HTML**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Day checker</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Click to show day</h1>
  <button id="checkday">Check!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "What day is it",
    "description": "This extension will find the date",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

**Image(19x19)**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM9wt.png

Comment: You should always include what the *expected* output is, as well as the *actual* output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action has to be dynamically linked after the DOM content has been loaded.
Due to security reasons, statically linked actions (onClick attribute for e.g.) would not work with Chrome extensions.

In your js file(popup.js), add this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.querySelector('#checkday').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
  // anything else you want to initialize on the page
});
```

That should get it to work.